# What would constitute an alternative to deep equality checks in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I have some state which is loaded into my container top level component from my API which is a template of a database construct and is considerably nested with objects and arrays. useEffect obviously only does referential shallow comparisons and thus fires every render despite whether or not the structure has changed. This is problematic because I wish to fire a useEffect hook every time it changes so the API can be notified of its new value.

I am aware that deep equality is expensive but it seems necessary in this example. I know of a hook which does deep equality. However question is would it be acceptable to use a separate piece of state for example "updated" perhaps setting it equal to the current time in milliseconds every time I am aware that the course has changed. If I added this piece of state to the dependency array I could circumvent the need for deep equality. What would be the drawbacks of this approach and would the be another more recommended approach?

Comment: "*thus fires every render despite whether or not the structure has changed.*" - why does the reference change, why do you construct a new object on every render? Surely the api state or db template is loaded only once.

Comment: Yes the initial item is loaded once but client side it is updated with the UI and these changes need to be reflected on the back end. I need to send the object back to the server every time it is updated however useEffect only does a shallow comparison with objects checking its reference which is always new causing renders despite any updates.

Comment: I don't see what sending the object back has to do with the `useEffect`. And "*its reference which is always new*" - why is that? Can you show us your code please? It shouldn't be a new object if you didn't update anything.

Comment: "its reference which is always new" I think I was wrong about this part. The sending the object back part was only context. I have since gone with use-deep-compare-effect. Essentially my question was if there existed a better way to determine an object had been updated than deep equality checks but it seems fast enough anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this library could be useful to you:
https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect

Comment: I was actually referring to this in my question. I was asking if the alternative of using an integer for instance in state and using that as a dependency to useEffect would not be faster and better than the above? So instead of doing this deep equality check have an int which we monitor for changes and change that ints state whenever we update the deep object?

Comment: I just used this instead please disregard the last comment